# Nothing happens after login while implementing Android facebook sdk integration

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to integrate my android app with facebook. Have tried out various options which did not work and so have again come back to the official facebook android sdk.

Currently, I am using this link: 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/
. I have reached step 6.3.

My queries are:

1. Do we need to install facebook.apk on an actual device as mentioned in step 6.3 of the above link. I am not using an emulator for this. Also, how do I install facebook.apk on an actual device if it is required.
2. When I run my app for the first time, it asks me to login on facebook and then the screen turns white and nothing else happens. On subsequent login, the app does not ask me to login but the screen just turns white.

In my app, I am trying to keep an options menu which would allow the user to post on his facebook wall. This is the code for onOptionsItemSelected() method

```
Intent postOnFacebookWallIntent = new Intent(this, FacebookConnect.class);
startActivity(postOnFacebookWallIntent);
```

This is the FacebookConnect.class. I have removed my appid.

```
public class FacebookConnect extends Activity {

    Facebook facebook = new Facebook("my appid");

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    facebook.authorize(this, new String[]{"email","publish_stream"},new DialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            Log.d("amit","on complete");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
            Log.d("amit","on error");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
            Log.d("amit","on dialog");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d("amit","on cancel");
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

This is the logcat:

```
02-08 19:25:48.969: D/Facebook-WebView(23512): Webview loading URL: https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?display=touch&client_id=000000000000&scope=email%2Cpublish_stream&type=user_agent&redirect_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess
02-08 19:25:49.019: V/webview(23512): OnSizeChanged: Enter 
02-08 19:25:53.909: D/Facebook-WebView(23512): Redirect URL: fbconnect://success#access_token=AAAE8SKdIsi0BAN7MxzphiPsODeMNJYb4EwGiKtSrZBgrlFrsdL425NCDfi076MBBV9wZCd2j2yyZChQFRCCcqnEVu35FATDxcMaCc69bgMamSVtt2E2&expires_in=3849&code=AQCHh8bKWESa5u-ZltTCYek5thJpmsTufBLiJdvv1koHlxhl7WDNFL7b1ev3QNAeW7AfYrzFOaV5rFaINesh9DC55Lu62yPrLIvJmMpZX7K-Hv01CVZuT92S0HxyMhNSzq1N0RMeI-H89vBrT85j03WM8uw-bzMo1VN_PWgA2aUibQtRZvkimXUh7J34u-p5VZ8
02-08 19:25:53.919: D/Facebook-authorize(23512): Login Success! access_token=AAAE8SKdIsi0BAN7MxzphiPsODeMNJYb4EwGiKtSrZBgrlFrsdL425NCDfi076MBBV9wZCd2j2yyZChQFRCCcqnEVu35FATDxcMaCc69bgMamSVtt2E2 expires=1328713202932
02-08 19:25:53.919: D/amit(23512): on complete
02-08 19:25:53.939: V/webview(23512): ZoomScale 3 mPreserveZoom: false
```

I have been stuck here for a few days and have tried out many things. So, kindly help.
Also, this is very new for me. So, forgive me if this is something very elementary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this link which is very useful and simple enough for beginners like me.

http://www.integratingstuff.com/2010/10/14/integrating-facebook-into-an-android-application/

I was able to post a message on my facebook by following the steps mentioned..

Answer (score -1):

I was also experiencing the same problem. I resolved it. Here is the change you should implement.
In Facebook SDK `com.facebook.android.LoginButton.java` class Replace

```
private final class ButtonOnClickListener implements OnClickListener {
           // within else part
            mFb.authorize(mActivity, mPermissions,
                    new LoginDialogListener());
}
```

with

```
private final class ButtonOnClickListener implements OnClickListener {
            // within else part
            mFb.authorize(mActivity, mPermissions,Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH,
                          new LoginDialogListener());
}
```

Comment: Thanks Muhammad.. I found the code mentioned by you in the Hackbook.java example. I have not used this in my code..I have pasted my entire code for facebook integration in my question.. I just want a user to share something on his facebook wall by clicking the share button in my app.. What portions of Hackbook.java example do I need in my code? Sorry..I am a bit new to this. The Hackbook.java example is a bit overwhelming for me and I found that the link http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/ is not very well written..